# How to turn a singularity sandbox container into a sif file ? (while preserving the sandbox)

Tags: singularity-container

I have built a Singularity sandbox container using this command:

```
sudo singularity build --sandbox ubuntu/ library://ubuntu
```

Now, I would like to copy/export this container as a *sif* file. But I cannot find how to do this in the [documentation](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so by reading the doc more carefully, it's apparently not possible to keep the changes made on a sandbox into a sif file, see [here](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/build_a_container.html#overview)

Comment: Correct. The sif is read-only filesystem and a sandbox uses a directory structure for its mutability.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo singularity build ubuntu.sif ubuntu/
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Creating SIF file...
INFO:    Build complete: ubuntu.sif
```

See https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.5/user-guide/build_a_container.html#converting-containers-from-one-format-to-another